What were the origins of The Wesleyan Quadrilateral?
In The Wesleyan Quadrilateral we see Wesley had four ways of reflecting on a passage:

Scripture
Tradition
Reason
Experience

If I squint a bit - this seems to follow Aristotle's Modes of Persuasion:

Logos from Reason
Ethos(Authority) from Tradition
Pathos(Emotion) from Experience

My question is: What were the origins of The Wesleyan Quadrilateral?

I know nothing about Aristotle or Greek philosophers, but I found a reference to the Wesleyan Quadrilateral here:
This article traces the origins of the Wesleyan Quadrilateral to the Anglican Church, with an addition made by Wesley:

>Glossary of Terms: Wesleyan Quadrilateral:
The phrase which has relatively recently come into use to describe the principal factors that John Wesley believed illuminate the core of the Christian faith for the believer. Wesley did not formulate the succinct statement now commonly referred to as the Wesley Quadrilateral. Building on the Anglican theological tradition, Wesley added a fourth emphasis, experience.


The resulting four components or "sides" of the quadrilateral are (1) Scripture, (2) tradition, (3) reason, and (4) experience.


For United Methodists, Scripture is considered the primary source and standard for Christian doctrine. Tradition is experience and the witness of development and growth of the faith through the past centuries and in many nations and cultures. Experience is the individual's understanding and appropriating of the faith in the light of his or her own life. Through reason the individual Christian brings to bear on the Christian faith discerning and cogent thought. These four elements taken together bring the individual Christian to a mature and fulfilling understanding of the Christian faith and the required response of worship and service.

Source: A Dictionary for United Methodists, Alan K. Waltz, Copyright 1991, Abingdon Press. Used by Permission.
Wesley added a fourth emphasis to the Anglican theological tradition – experience.  The four “sides” of the quadrilateral are (1) Scripture, (2) Tradition, (3) Reason and (4) Experience.  Methodists use Scripture as their primary source and standard for Christian doctrine.  Tradition is experience and the witness of development and growth of the faith through the past centuries and in many nations and cultures.  Reason brings discernment and cogent thought to bear on the Christian faith.  Experience is the individual’s understanding and appropriating of the faith in the light of his or her own life.
NOTE: In mathematics, a quadrilateral is a four-sided figure, something having four straight sides. It applies to objects.  God is not an object. Neither can God be measured by scientific instruments because God is outwith our physical world.  God is Spirit.
